# Facebook - email accounts - Page and profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-integration

I would like to request that notifications / messages posted to my Facebook business page are sent to my business email, not my personal one as set in my Facebook profile. Is this possible or do all notifications get sent to the email account from your personal profile?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a second Facebook account with your business email address and set that account as a co-owner of that Facebook page.

Alternatively, you can setup a auto-forward rule inside Gmail.